# bad texture mapping on sides of a cylinder

Tags: texturing, uv

I would like to apply a texture to an cylinder object in Blender cycles.
Below is the result when I apply the texture to the entire mesh:

- Mapping OK for the Upper and bottom circular faces.
- Mapping not OK
  for the lateral side, the texture is applied to each single
  subdivision face.

My goal is to apply the texture to the entire lateral side as a single surface.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While using the basic generated texture co-ordinates can be easy and helpful in some cases, you want to use UV-Unwrapping to get full control of how your texture looks. BlenderCookie has an [introduction tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/01/21/intro_uvmapping/) that explains more.

The basics are -

First mark the seams, this is where the edges are "cut" to get the model laying flat on a 2d texture image. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>->Mark Seams with mark the selected edges.

[image]

Then you unwrap - Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>U</kbd>->Unwrap

[image]

Now when you set the mapping to UV for the texture you will get the same bricks texture on the top as well as the sides.

[image]

For more control you can also assign [different materials](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Multiple_Materials) to the top and sides.

[image]